# Can reading a file be as dangerous as executing it

Tags: perl, security, owasp

In Perl, if any file type is allowed to be uploaded to a server (not in web root) and consequently downloaded, can this be dangerous? It's not being executed as such but read as binary.

Comment: Data is just bytes. If you can get the language to execute those bytes, that's another story, but at that point you're subverting the intended action of the language through some exploit.

Comment: Sure it can! See the OWASP page on [Unrestricted File Upload](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload),
the InfoSec page on [Complete File Upload Vulnerabilities](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/file-upload-vulnerabilities/),
the CWE page on [Unrestricted Upload of File with Dangerous Type](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/434.html), and the SANS recommendations for [8 Basic Rules to Implement Secure File Uploads](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/12/28/8-basic-rules-to-implement-secure-file-uploads) for details.

Comment: One other note - this is partially a user-education issue. The users that are downloading the file are the ones at risk, and need to be trained to understand that the source of the files could be in question.

Comment: If the data is parsed in any way (e.g. if it has an XML extension you decide to parse it), then you can also be vulnerable to exploits via the parser. Same for handling file names perhaps inserted to db.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is belongs on a security stackexchange.

Comment: It's less likely to be dangerous, but not 100% safe. Especially in the middle ground where the line between 'content rendering' and 'scripting language' gets increasingly thin.

Comment: Simple version: Yes, because you could end up executing it without intending to. It could be from the reading itself (buffer overflow), or from what you do with what you read.

Comment: Appreciate the answers and comments and that this may be off topic but it was directed principally at the reading of the file using perl's open/read. Seems that preventing the file from being uploaded in the first place is where the effort should be spent.

Comment: @ianbeks Reading the file is safe (Unicode encoding people might have something to add about that) but once you've read it who knows what you'll do with that data. Who knows what the functions you pass your data into will do with it.  This is why [taint mode exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) although its extremely global nature makes it difficult to implement in production.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll reiterate @ThisSuitIsBlackNot's links to file upload security considerations...

- [Unrestricted File Upload Vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload)
- [Complete File Upload Vulnerabilities](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/file-upload-vulnerabilities/) which is not complete at all but includes some good examples.
- [CWE-434: Unrestricted Upload of File with Dangerous Type](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/434.html)
- [8 Basic Rules to Implement Secure File Uploads](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/12/28/8-basic-rules-to-implement-secure-file-uploads)

These can be boiled down to...

- Dangers to your server

  - Injecting a special file or file extension which the server will execute.

    - .htaccess (per-directory Apache configuration file)
    - .php, .asp, .cgi, etc...
  - Injecting a system file outside the download directory.

    - /etc/passwd or ../../../../etc/passwd
  - Exploiting a flaw in a processing library

    - Image resize
    - XML/JSON parsing
  - SQL injection attack

    - Filename
    - File metadata
  - Shell injection attack

    - Filename
  - Buffer overflow

    - File size
    - HTTP upload size
    - Filename size
    - Directory depth
  - Denial Of Service by filling the disk
- Dangers to others

  - Phishing attack

    - Upload a malicious .html file making it appear the URL is coming from your (trusted) host.
    - Upload a malicious .js file and refer to it from elsewhere in your domain (perhaps a forum post) to circumvent XSS attack defenses.
  - Using your service as an anonymous attack vector

    - BOTnet control files
    - Pirated files including torrents
    - Personal data for blackmail or harassment purposes
    - Trojan/virus files